# How to create multiple torify instances for bash scripts?

Tags: bash, curl, tor

**What we have:**

Multiple tor connections open at different ports.

**What we want:**

Create torify2, torify3, ... to handle multiple requests from different bash scripts simultanously.

**Like:**

```
bash_1.sh
torify curl ifconfig.me
...

bash_2.sh
torify2 curl ifconfig.me
...

bash_3.sh
torify3 curl ifconfig.me
...
```

*I am new to stackoverflow. Feel free to comment so I can improve my skills in how to ask questions.*

Comment: I am not understanding what the torifyN parts are supposed to be?

Comment: So that you can handle multiple e.g. curl requests with different IPs at the same time.

Comment: hmmm .. I wasn't clear enough, are you saying you have torifyN (N up to what??) executables?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least a couple of easy methods to do what you want since multiple Tor instances are already up and running.

Torify just calls torsocks so if you read the man page for torsocks, there aren't any options for specifying host/port for Tor, but it does use a config file which you can switch using the `TORSOCKS_CONF_FILE` environment variable.

The location of your config file may vary, but check `/etc/tor/torsocks.conf` for the default.  Make a copy for each Tor instance, and change the `TorPort` in each file to a different Tor port.

Then, you can test that it works by running:

```
TORSOCKS_CONF_FILE=/tmp/torsocks-1.conf torsocks curl ifconfig.me
```

You can either run each instance like that, specifying a different config, or if you want to put that into a script, try:

#### torify1.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

TORSOCKS_CONF_FILE=/path/to/torsocks1.conf torsocks "$@"
```

Make one of the above scripts for each conf file and Tor SOCKS port you have running.  The `"$@"` just passes all the command line arguments to your script to Torify.

You'd just run your script like: `torify1.sh curl -v --compressed http://ifconfig.me/`

Hope that helps.

Comment: You sure you don't mean torrc file? You can create multiple torrc files torrc1 torrc2 etc with different ports and data paths and then use bash scripts to tie torify (torsocks) to each respective one.

Comment: They said they already have "Multiple tor connections open at different ports" so it sounds like the torrc part is done and they just need to modify torsocks configuration to connect to the different ports.